# PHP - mkdir() creates first recursive directory, but not the ones inside it

Tags: php, permissions, directory

I've come with a strange issue in PHP

I have the following code

```
function subirFotoTemporal($idhash)
{
    global $target_dir;
    $dirfinal = $target_dir."temporales/".$idhash;
    if (!is_dir($dirfinal))
        mkdir($dirfinal, 0664, true);     
    [...]
```

However, I get a warning in the last line: `mkdir(): Permission denied [...]`

This causes the subsequent code to fail since it depends on the directory created in this stage. Turns out that the directory `temporales` is created, but the directory based on `$idhash` is not. The `temporales` folder is created with a 0644 permission set instead of the 0664 specified in the command.

I checked similar questions on the site and I checked every file in the Apache enviroment is set to the www-data owner.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: do you have root access to your server ?

Comment: Everything is being done on a local environment, so yes.

Comment: okay, and I noticed you did not define anything to `$target_dir`. eg `global $target_dir; $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: `$target_dir` is defined outside the scope of the function, the contents of the variable are irrelevant (`__DIR__."/foo/"`).

Comment: try using `0755`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a permission problem as suggested by @JamesBond.

Further testing revealed that I needed to set the Execute permission to the Owner. `07xx`

Comment: You can learn more about *NIX permissions here: http://permissions-calculator.org/info/